# Combobox Style 'csDropDownList' in Delphi

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

I have created one form in delphi 7 and added one combobox on it. The combobox contains the list of items. I dont want that user can enter the value to Combobox so i have set

```
combobox.style := csDropDownList;
```

But thorugh code i want to use `combobox.text := 'New Item';` but its not working. Note that the text I want to show is not in the list of items and I don't want to add it there. Please is any solution to this?

Comment: Is the item you want always "New Item" or is it different each time?

Comment: You need to reconsider your design. What you are talking about is not a drop down list.

Comment: @ain: The text will be different also.i want to set text through code only. thanks.

Comment: As David said, your UI design is wrong. You should provide the dropdown list with the available items, and have a separate "New Item" button. This makes the interface more clear to the user, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is simply not the way the Windows combobox control works.

However, if you insist, and you don't care that your users will get confused, you can set `Style` to `csDropDown` and then do

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Key := #0;
end;
```

as the combobox' `OnKeyPress` event. Then the user cannot enter text manually, but can only choose from the items in the list. However, *you* can still set the text to anything you like (even if it isn't in the list) by setting the `Text` property:

```
ComboBox1.Text := 'Sample';
```

Comment: Yes you can, as long as it's in the list.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Of course, but the OP wrote "Note that the text I want to show is not in the list of items and I don't want to add it there."

Comment: I did downvoting it when your answer was just a single (false) line. Undone it now you promoted it to a real and suitable answer.

Comment: But then user can use copy / paste to enter something which is not in the list.

Comment: @GolezTrol: The first line is still the same, but it isn't false. In Microsoft Windows, you *cannot* set the 'text' of a combobox control with the 'drop down list' style to anything that is not in the list.

Comment: @ain: Yes, but the workaround for that is pretty simple. Still, I don't think you should confuse the user at all.

Comment: But as long as you edit your answer *and* your comment while I'm responding to them, as wel as @ain is editing the original question to suit your answer, I can't make much sense out of it. :s That line "Note that the text I want to show is not in the list of items and I don't want to add it there." wasn't added by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `ItemIndex` property. You can get `ComboBox.Items.IndexOf('New Item')` to get the index of that text, if you don't already know it.

```
Combobox.ItemIndex := Combobox.Items.IndexOf('New item');
```

Comment: Then you can't. That's the whole essence of having a drop down list. You can't select anything other than what's in the list. Even from code.

Comment: A sort of work-around would be to use `ComboBox.ItemIndex := ComboBox.Items.Add('New Item');`, but this would add 'New Item' to the list.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround if it violates the OP's preconditions.

Answer (score 2):

Below sample code demonstrates how you can draw custom text in response to a `WM_DRAWITEM` message sent to the ComboBox control's parent window (this should be the form for the sample to work, otherwise subclassing controls or full drawing of items of the control would be necessary).

To receive this message set the `Style` property of the control to 'csOwnerDrawFixed', but do not put a handler for the `OnDrawItem` event so that default drawing should be applied in all other cases that we intervene drawing.

The sample sets a text when `ItemIndex` is -1, but it can be adapted/tweaked otherwise. Note that the drawing code is not complete or accurate, the sample just demonstrates a way how it can be done:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    [..]
  private
    procedure WMDrawItem(var Msg: TWMDrawItem); message WM_DRAWITEM;
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.WMDrawItem(var Msg: TWMDrawItem);
var
  Font: HFONT;
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.Ctl = ComboBox1.Handle) and (Msg.DrawItemStruct.itemID = $FFFFFFFF) and
      ((Msg.DrawItemStruct.itemAction and ODA_DRAWENTIRE) = ODA_DRAWENTIRE) then begin

    Font := SelectObject(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ComboBox1.Canvas.Font.Handle);
    SelectObject(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

    if (Msg.DrawItemStruct.itemState and ODS_SELECTED) = ODS_SELECTED then begin
      SetDCBrushColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clHighlight));
      SetBkColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clHighlight));
      SetTextColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clHighlightText));
    end else begin
      SetDCBrushColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clWindow));
      SetBkColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clWindow));
      SetTextColor(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clWindowText));
    end;

    FillRect(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, Msg.DrawItemStruct.rcItem, 0);
    TextOut(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, 4, 4, '_no_selected_item_', 18);

    SelectObject(Msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC, Font);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the normal thing, to display something in the ComboBox when no selection has yet been made. Instant of a blank rectangle. Imagine a form full of blank comboboxes... ;)

What I've seen most programmers do is have the first item as the title to display in the ComboBox.

So, in FormCreate (after you've populated the ComboBox), you set its ItemIndex to 0, and this displays the title.

In its OnChange event you can choose to take no action if item 0 is selected ("real" items then have base 1 for index), or get ItemIndex-1 and skip action if < 0.

Must be a super common complaint from everyone who has used Comboboxes the first time. I can't understand how none of the coders recognize it.

All Borland et al would have had to do was to initialize a new ComboBox with ItemIndex=0 and the confusion would have been gone. It's certainly not obvious that you have to set index 0 - since you see the blank line when clicked, the logical conclusion is that *it* has index 0. Probably they wanted to give designers the option to add a label outside the combobox instead.